# How to get unique elements from a numpy array containing numpy arrays with different lengths?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a nested numpy array - it contains a lot of other numpy sub-arrays, but the sub-arrays have different lengths. The main array `arr_main` looks something like this:

```
>>> print(main_arr)
array([[array([3.5525, ..., 4.0138, 4.0139], dtype=float32)],
       [array([3.5525, ..., 4.0138, 4.0139], dtype=float32)],
                                ...
       [array([3.5525, ..., 4.0138, 4.0139], dtype=float32)]],
  dtype=object)
```

What I want to do is to extract only the unique sub-arrays from the big, main array, so I want to do something like

```
np.unique(main_arr)
```

but this results in the error message `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4613,) (4615,)`. I guess, this is due to some sub-arrays having different lengths.

How can I extract the unique sub-arrays from `main_arr`? If you know some solution that is not relying on numpy it will be also appreciated! tnx

Comment: that object dtype array is, for all practical purposes, a list.

Comment: @hpaulj Alright, do you have a suggestion for me? If I turn the object into a list will this help me with finding the unique elements?

Comment: `unique` works by sorting the entries so identical ones arecnext to each other.  That means `a>b` comparjson has to make sense.  Another approach is use python `set`, but that requires hashable objects, ,ike tuples, not arrays. Separating your arrays into groups of like sized ones may be the only way to go.  You need to think more about what makes your arrays 'unique', and not depend on some numpy magic to do all the 'thinking'.

Answer (score 2):

The numpy unique function on works on 1 dimensional arrays but here's some logic you could deploy to get an array of unique arrays:

```
import numpy as np

# Create example array of sub arrays
a = np.array([ 
    np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([4, 5, 6, 7]), 
    np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([4, 5, 6, 7])])
# Build array of unique sub arrays
unique = []
for sub_a in a: 
    if not any([np.array_equal(i, sub_a) for i in unique]): 
        unique.append(sub_a)
unique_array = np.array(unique)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionnary regrouping arrays by length and then extracting only uniques ones.

```py
for array in main_arr:
    n = array.size
    if n in d:
        d[n].append(array)
     else:
        d[n] = np.array([array])

new_array = np.empty()

for k in d.keys():
    new_array.append(np.unique(d[k]))
```

However, extracting unique arrays is a heavy algorithm...

Answer (score 1):

You might like to think more which groups of items of `main_arr` could be compared in order to identify whether they have duplicates. The question is self-explanatory. You need to group it by lenghts of arrays you've got in `main_arr`. After that you can call `np.unique` on these groups.

```
main_arr = np.array([np.array([3.5525, 3.7895, 4.0139], dtype=float),
              np.array([3.5525, 3.7895, 4.0139], dtype=float),
              np.array([3.5525, 4.0138, 4.0139, 4.1], dtype=float),
              np.array([3.5525, 4.0138, 4.0139], dtype=float),
              np.array([3.5525, 4.0138, 4.0139, 4.1], dtype=float),
              np.array([3.5525, 3.7895, 4.0138, 4.0139, -1], dtype=float)], dtype=object)

from itertools import groupby
groups = [list(g) for k,g in groupby(sorted(main_arr, key=len), len)] 
# (...) instead of [...] is a better choice in order to avoid double iteration
>>> groups
[[array([3.5525, 3.7895, 4.0139]),
  array([3.5525, 3.7895, 4.0139]),
  array([3.5525, 4.0138, 4.0139])],
 [array([3.5525, 4.0138, 4.0139, 4.1   ]),
  array([3.5525, 4.0138, 4.0139, 4.1   ])],
 [array([ 3.5525,  3.7895,  4.0138,  4.0139, -1.    ])]]

>>> [np.unique(g, axis=0) for g in groups]
[array([[3.5525, 3.7895, 4.0139],
        [3.5525, 4.0138, 4.0139]]),
 array([[3.5525, 4.0138, 4.0139, 4.1   ]]),
 array([[ 3.5525,  3.7895,  4.0138,  4.0139, -1.    ]])]
```

You are able to concatenate all these arrays but then you're going to have another data structure `numpy` processing is not designed for if you do this.

Note: I've changed an initial data a little bit.